# Getting an array from a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have an express application, where I have a function where I want to return a promise and return that from an endpoint.

here is my function where I return a promise.

My express endpoint:

```js
app.get('/logs', (req, res) =>{
    const logs = socketNotification.fetchFiles();

});
```

and then I have my function, where I return a promise.

```
const fetchFiles = () => {
    return logs.then( file => {
        const lines = file.lines;
        lines.splice(-1);
        const JSONlogs = lines.map(line => {
            return({
                log: JSON.parse(line)
            });
        });
    })
}


module.exports = {
    fetchFiles
}
```

right now I just return the object `JSONlogs` that is stored inside the function. Is there a way just to extract the object from the function. I tried with `async/await`, but I was unsure of the placement of the keywords.

Comment: extract what object exactly?

Comment: i have edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: Where is the `fetchFiles` function?

Comment: @oktapodia in another file/module

Comment: I mean, in your example

Comment: sorry... i have edited to fit your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review the following revised snippet for a skeleton to follow;

```
async function fetchFiles(params) {
    const file = await logs();
    const lines = file.lines
    lines.splice(-1)
    const JSONlogs = lines.map(line => {
        return ({
            log: JSON.parse(line)
        })
    });
    return JSONlogs;
}

app.get('/logs', async (req, res) =>{
    const logs = await socketNotification.fetchFiles()

})
```

The first step is to make the route async. Then make the fetchFiles async. The log function must be async as well. Here is a brief tutorial describing the functionality in more detail. 
[link](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: The other mistake was that you did not return the JSONFlags array

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to return the express response with the following with async/await

if you want to use the `await` keyword, you must add the `async` keyword in front of this function

```
app.get('/logs', async (req, res) =>{
    const logs = await socketNotification.fetchFiles()

    return res.status(200).json(logs);
});
```

Not clear what `logs` is in your function